# If you're also a phycis SE user, why do you think MSE is more active compared to PSE?

Tags: discussion

https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/why-physics-se-is-much-more-inactive-compared-to-mse

I asked this question in physics SE meta, and I hope we can also discuss this question here to see the difference.

I once took myself as example, but it might be a sampling bias.

If you're also a mathematical physics student or a PSE user, what's your opinion?

Thanks for kindly discussion :)

Comment: Math applies to things that aren't physics. Obviously there's less physics done here than there, but everybody studies math, and few study physics.

Comment: It's because physicsforums soaks up all their PSQs

Comment: @AlexanderGruber What does PSQ mean?

Comment: @Andrews Problem-Statement-Question. A post that states a problem and nothing more.

Comment: Your Physics.SE version of this Question included more context than what is posted above.  I'm not a Physics student or active PSE participant, so I won't attempt an answer, but some additional context would be welcome.  Any two SE sites will satisfy that one is more active than the other, and asking why (for two particular sites) needs some premise about whether that reality defies expectations or is considered desirable vs. undesirable.

Comment: Physics.SE does not allow homework questions to be posted. Or answered. We never managed to get a similar policy to pass. By popular demand of people wanting to either ask or answer such.

Comment: Everybody takes math. Hardly anybody takes physics. Case closed.